# How can I set up a bootstrap grid of 12 columns with a width of 960px but have rows being 1280 wide?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

How can I set up a 960px bootstrap grid for 12 columns but have each row be 1280px wide,  so only the rows background images/colors are 1280px wide and have a padding on both sides of 160px (1280-960 / 2)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the bootstrap framework then you would use the `<div class="row">` outside of a `<div class="container">`

The container is the element that has the width in CSS whereas the row doesn't have a width so that would span the width of the page that you have while the content would be contained in the container.

From the bootstrap CSS :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```